# Where are The Rift and The Reach?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Does anyone know where they are? I can't seem to find them on my map, or remember where they are at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Rift is the Hold in the south east-most portion of the map. It's capital is Riften.

The Reach is the west-most hold of the map. It's capital is Markath.

[image]

Picture credit to the [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Maps).

Comment: Thanks so much. It was giving me a headache. it seems the random guards/authorities talking to you is linked to having a bounty. I have 5 gold bounties in both of these areas for some reason. Now I just need to pay them off.